# How can just a few votes bring an alert to my privilege of asking questions?

Tags: discussion, support, bug

I am now getting this message when I try to ask a question on SO:

> Wait! Some of your past questions have not been well-received, you're in danger being blocked from asking any more.

My reputation is 1385 at the time of this writing. So far, I have asked 29 questions on the SO community, which received 31 up-votes and 3 down-votes (3 of which, in my humble opinion, were not justified or, at least, debatable). I realize that the score is not to the roof, but it is at least, respectable. My questions' up-votes clearly show that at least some people appreciate them.

I revised all my questions so far and did not find the need to modify them, so I will not. Now I realize that other people may have another opinion, but really? Is the privilege of asking questions so sensitive to the point that 2 or 3 down-votes jeopardize my privilege?

Questions:

- Is there possibly a major bug with the system?
- If my statistics justify such a fragile situation, shouldn't the algorithm be more vigilant in filtering the justifications when people down-vote a question?

Comment: 1385? Your current reputation is 133 though?

Comment: Your reputation is 133 on Stack Overflow. The question ban algorithm only applies on each site separately and only takes into account questions you've posted on each site. "*Is the privilege of asking questions be sensitive to the point of 2 or 3 down-votes jeopardize my privilege ?*" and again, the algorithm takes ***all*** questions on the site into account. Not just ones with a low score, not even just non-deleted ones. See [What can I do when getting “We are no longer accepting questions/answers from this account”?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255583) which lists all we really know.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat 1385 network-wide.

Comment: You've also only asked 10 questions on Stack Overflow. Is the 29 questions also a network-wide number? As far as I am aware, question rate limits and bans are calculated per site. You should just be looking at your [Stack Overflow profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7474548/fred-cailloux) if you've received this warning on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Thank you all for enlightening my comprehension of the SO algorithm.  Yes, the statistics presented in my question were pertaining to all sites. Now I know better.  
Though I strongly suspect that I am not the only one with this perception, I am of the opinion that the question could help many others that had or have the same perception. Hence, IMO the question is quite useful to the community. So then, how would any of you 6 who down-voted my question see the irrelevancy is beyond my comprehension.

Comment: "IMO the question is quite useful to the community" -- considering that in some 4 years your questions managed to collect a total of 3 upvotes, it would seem that this opinion is not shared by the community.

Comment: @FredCailloux on the downvote tooltip there are reasons, one of them is that the question *does not show any research effort*. Given the information available via existing questions and answers I imagine the downvotes are coming from you appearing not to have read any of them.

Comment: Just to be clear: no, questions like "What lubricant is suitable for switch contact?" on an electrical engineering website don't demonstrate an ability to ask programming questions according to the programming-question site's standards.

Comment: Your network profile About (& others) says user37216 but that's just chemistry.se.

Comment: @Robert Longson – To the contrary, I read them all.  I can assure you that before I propose a question on any of the sites, I always do significant search. Just like asking about the possible reason I was prevented from asking further questions. Searching for answers could not bring fruits 100% of the time. Being judged on such a criteria appear somewhat peculiar to me, to say the least. But hey… who am I to judge ? If that is how the community feels, so be it. Honestly, I thought the question was valuable, not only to me but to others as well. I’ll try to be a better human next time.

Comment: @FredCailloux So you're saying that in year 2021, no "significant" amount of research would enlighten you on something as fundamental as bitfields? https://stackoverflow.com/q/70010622/3962537 | The questions you state in your post seem to point at external sources (there's a bug, the system is broken,...). Have you considered that perhaps what you're doing (or how you are doing it) is the source of the problem?

Comment: @FredCailloux if you do that research then you need to include it in your question, perhaps that's where you're going wrong and if you start to do that people might stop downvoting your questions. There is no indication in this question that you've read and understood other Q&A that discusses how voting works or how question bans work.

Comment: *"Though I strongly suspect that I am not the only one with this perception"* - no doubt about it. Little to be done about it though. It's all documented, but to read documentation you need to want to read documentation. People just wing it instead, and this is the one site where you can't do that.

Comment: *If my statistics justify such a fragile situation, shouldn't the algorithm be more vigilant in filtering the justifications when people down-vote a question?* No because people aren't required to justify their downvotes. Proposals to the contrary have been suggested and rejected many times. I updated the dupe list to reflect this.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Firstly each site is treated on its own merits so you can be banned here and yet still ask questions on other sites. Only your activity on this site counts for whether or not you're banned here. Other positive actions on other sites only count for those sites. You may be a great gardener and yet a terrible programmer for instance and the system allows for that to be the case.

You've asked 10 questions on Stack Overflow and only 7 of them are visible so three of your questions have been deleted. Presumably those are negatively scoring.

Therefore 30% of your questions have been deleted, either by you or by the system. If those questions have any answers then the question ban treats doing that particularly harshly. Even if they don't, the negative or zero score of such questions still count against you.

The total aggregate score of all your visible questions is 2, that's not great either. If you add on the score of your deleted questions you may find that you're overall negative and that's why you're getting a ban warning.

If you don't want to improve your questions you don't have to but the consequence is that you might get banned. The system is warning you of that in advance so ignore it if you wish but then you'll have to accept the consequences.

So it doesn't seem there's any bug in the system here. Nor is there any reason to restrict downvotes, after all you're not asking for all your upvotes to be audited are you? You have to accept the rough with the smooth here.

Comment: "[take the rough with the smooth](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/take%20the%20rough%20with%20the%20smooth) *idiom chiefly British*". While it clear from the context what you wanted to say... consider using rough language for smooth understanding :)

Comment: @Alexei Levenkov please explain this one. It's a bit rough for me as a native french speaking. Though I read the proposed link "in addition to the good or pleasant things" ??  Where do yo see the "pleasant" here ?

Comment: @FredCailloux: Robert can answer himself but until then, I believe he is referring to your displeasure at your downvotes and that you need to accept that you'll get some undeserved downvotes (the rough) but also some undeserved upvotes (the smooth). In other words, don't become overly sensitive to downvotes.

Comment: People generally find upvotes are pleasant (smooth) and downvotes unpleasant (rough).

Comment: Hmm, they both feel the same to me. Is that a userscript that you're using to provide the pliant/tactile feedback when casting votes?